# Fingerprint login option not available in Dell XPS 15 9570 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 15 9570 laptop and cannot see any "Fingerprint Login" option under Users settings. I have tried many solutions suggested by people online, but none have worked out.

[image: Fingerprint option not present in Ubuntu20.04 in Dell XPS 15 9570]

Answer (score 3):

I just managed to work it out on Lenovo T520 with Upek fingerprint sensor (ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor)

Intalled fprint :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fprintd
```

Enrolled fingerpirnt via Gnome gui: enroll finger print via **settings** / **users** / **Fingerprint Login**

Intalled fprint pam settings:

```
sudo apt install libpam-fprintd
```

Enrolled fingerprint login on pamconfiguraiton :

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

and select Enable Fingerprint authentication

I hope it works for you guys.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly on my Dell XPS Plus 9320 running PopOS 22.04

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me on Dell XPS 15 9520, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: It unfortunately didn't work on my Dell Latitude 5530 with Ubuntu Unity 22.04 LTS. Btw, lsusb didn't even recognize it although when I had Linux Mint 21.0 on here it recognized it and automatically suggested a driver for it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the information on Linux Hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:27c6-5395&hwid=401e4e7bdfc4), the fingerprint reader can sometimes be detected when using Linux Kernel 5.12 or newer, but there is no (publicly known) driver available. Because there is no driver, there will be no option to use the fingerprint reader in the Authentication options.

As the current line of Kernels can at least *detect* the device now, hopefully there will be support for this reader added to one of the driver packages in the near future.