# I can't use fingerprint sensor in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I can't find fingerprint sensors settings in Ubuntu 22.04 installed on my notebook (XPS 13 Dell). I've tried "settings > Users", but there is no fingerprint option there. Do I have to install separately or it is provided by Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1344385/1617288) fixed my problem, have a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also running the same setup and had the same issue but the fix is pretty straightforward. First of all makes sure that the OS recognises that the fingerprint sensor exists. You can do this by running

```
lsusb
```

You should see an entry that is about a fingerprint scanner.
Then you can download and install the needed software with

```
wget http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
```

If you get any dependency errors just apt install the relevant dependency and try again. After you install everything you should be able to see a fingerprint option appear in the Users settings. According to the original source there is a reboot necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, credit to the author of this post https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/sp3iky/how_to_enable_fingerprint_login_in_ubuntu_on_dell/

Comment: This may have worked for 20.04 LTS but it does not for (recent updates of) 22.04 because of the libfprint library update. You need to use the updated versions, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Enabling fingerprint for login, screensaver unlock, graphical sudo password prompts in Ubuntu 22.04 on *Dell Inspiron 14 7425 2-in-1* requires the following commands:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:639c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
...
$ sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd
$ fprintd-enroll
$ sudo pam-auth-update --enable fprintd
```

Full details:

- [`man fprintd-enroll`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fprintd/fprintd-enroll.1.en.html)
- [`man pam-auth-update`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/pam-auth-update.8.html)

Comment: worked like a charm even in terminal on my dell xps 15, Kubuntu 22.04

Comment: Thank you. For Latitude 5440 users - ```0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 58200``` is your fingerprint sensor. Driver's here: http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-broadcom/

Comment: Works on ThinkPad T14s G4 (on Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 3):

The Dell XPS 13 likely has a Goodix fingerprint reader, which is not open source. There were some updates to libfprint/fprintd that broke compatibility with the driver.

A bug report was opened and in the mean time this is fixed.
Use the packages from Andy Chi as mentioned in the bug report to test:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/+bug/1966911

Multiple users ( including myself ) have reported this to work now, so I think the packages will be part of 22.04 soon, just keep an eye on the bug (they are in the proposed channel now, which you can enable to test too).

Note that if anything is not working as expected, there may be a configuration issue.

Please report if you have this working now and if not, check the bug report and provide details so you can be helped.

[update]
A fix has been released as a result of the bug report. Make sure to read it and see if your problem is solved. A full update should give you a working setup if you were affected by the bug
[/update]

Comment: Small update, the fixed package for 22.04 for Goodix can be found here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/+bug/1966911?comments=all . It is unclear to me if they will be part of any main repo, but I asked the question in the bug report. If this breaks in future versions, file a bug against the package as was done. I just confirmed the driver working on my XPS 9700 with lsusb output : Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint

Answer (score 1):

When you installed the driver and restarted the OS but you still don't see the option **Fingerprint Login** in **User Settings**, you may try:

`sudo service fprintd status`

In my case the error was:

`fprintd[12337]: Impossible to load module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfprint-2/tod-1/libfprint-2-tod-1-broadcom.so: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file:>`

I installed **libssl**:

`sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb`

And restarted **fprintd** service:

`sudo service fprintd restart`

After that service status shows: `systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon` and I could see the option **Fingerprint Login** in **User Settings**.

Comment: BTW, if you are able to add a fingerprint but you see a service error **Failed to query prints: "Driver failed to provide a list of prints"**, try to add more fingers.