# Fingerprint sensor in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I am using ubuntu in hp 15-ds2007tx but couldn't find a way to use the fingerprint sensor. Are there any package to be installed?

Comment: find the vendor id and see if it is on the unsuported list: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/wiki/-/wikis/Unsupported-Devices also
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406999/i-cant-use-fingerprint-sensor-in-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't use fingerprint sensor in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406999/i-cant-use-fingerprint-sensor-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to install the drivers for the fingerprint sensors, I use a Dell Inspiron Laptop and it has a fingerprint sensor too and the packages for the fingerprint sensor got loaded automatically once I connected to the internet because the company that makes the fingerprint sensors (Goodix) had released some packages recently for ubuntu basically open-sourcing and stuff for a layman. Try looking for drivers manually though. First look at the manufacturer's name and the device version and then search for the drivers online. Hope this helps and if you need to ask more details or anything just reply to this.