# Dell Precision 5540 fingerprint login setup ubuntu 22.04

Tags: login, dell, 22.04

I tired following this: https://itsfoss.com/fingerprint-login-ubuntu/

but, my user settings doesn't show the fingerprint option. Then, I tried: [I can't use fingerprint sensor in ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406999/i-cant-use-fingerprint-sensor-in-ubuntu-22-04)

But, it didn't help.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Before anything else you need to confirm whether or not your device is supported, obviously.

Comment: It would be useful to determine the specific fingerprint hardware used on this system. From a bit of searching, I'd guess it may be `ID 27c6:5395` (a Goodix device, source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_15_(7590)), but it would be good to confirm. Please perform a `lsusb` command and post the results of this output.

Comment: @richbl 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader

Comment: @psimeson, thanks. As I had suspected, this device does not have Linux driver support. There is/was a project that attempted to reverse engineer this device, here: https://github.com/IDerr/Goodix92. For my own part, I had a Dell laptop that also had a fingerprint reader that had no Linux support. My current laptop is a Lenovo ;).

Comment: It seems like the solution is to get a different machine :) I thought it would be nice to use the hardware that I have already in the machine. Thanks a lot @richbl

Comment: @psimeson, agreed. I used to own a Dell 9560 and the Validity fingerprint hardware was not supported under Linux, so I never had the opportunity to use the hardware. My next (current) laptop is a Lenovo, and everything "just works." Never again will I purchase a Dell (the least stable laptop I've ever owned). Best of outcomes to you.