# How to use Fingerprint for login in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: login, security, 22.04, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I am currently using ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish and I have the following fingerprint reader in my laptop

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 27c6:5301 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
```

I searched for many solutions as how to install fingerprint driver for the above device. All I found and tried is to install

```
fprintd libfprint-2-2 libfprint-2-tod1 libpam-fprintd
```

I also found that the goodix fingerprint requires one more package to be installed and I installed it with the following commands.

```
wget http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.6-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.6-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
```

Then I tried making it default by changing the default from no to yes in /usr/share/pam-configs/fprintd like

```
Name: Fingerprint authentication
Default: yes
Priority: 260
Conflicts: fprint
Auth-Type: Primary
Auth:
        [success=end default=ignore]    pam_fprintd.so max-tries=3 timeout=10 # debug
```

Then also updated the pam-auth-update to enable fprintd with the following command

```
sudo pam-auth-update --enable fprintd
```

and also made sure that the fingerprint authentication is chosen by running

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

I rebooted the system after all the above steps and checked for the fprintd service status and it is active.

```
● fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-07-11 21:57:29 IST; 14s ago
       Docs: man:fprintd(1)
   Main PID: 4660 (fprintd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 18797)
     Memory: 1.5M
        CPU: 173ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/fprintd.service
             └─4660 /usr/libexec/fprintd
```

But I did not get any option for fingerprint enroll in my setting of my GUI. I also tried  fprintd-enroll and the output is as follows

```
# fprintd-enroll 
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

I don't know how should I enable my fingerprint sensor in my ubuntu 22.04. Thus reaching out for help. Thanks in advance... :)

P.S: Additional information about the kernel version

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS                
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-39-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Many modern distributions [can detect that device](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:27c6-5301), but there is no driver for it at this time. Unfortunately, that means you'll need to wait until someone can reverse-engineer the device so that it can be used in Linux 

Comment: @matigo this is sad actually, thinkpad upon release even with China OEM will have direct support for it. Seems Dell is 2nd class or Dell is lazy to release the drivers.. ugh...

Comment: This may be answered in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406999/i-cant-use-fingerprint-sensor-in-ubuntu-22-04 (pointing that lsusb must see fingerprint sensor) and another reply noted there https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341930/fingerprint-login-option-not-available-in-dell-xps-15-9570-ubuntu-20-04/1344385#1344385 which explains how to do it.

Comment: @Timur yeah. It is available while listing using lsusb. but the problem is that there is no driver for that particular for it now.