# Updates always appear but I get a 404 error for some PPAs

Tags: apt, updates, fingerprint-reader

I get the following errors when I try to update software from the fingerprint PPA:

```
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu jammy Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu jammy
```

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources, so all security checks are on you to perform. A PPA that last saw attention in 2018 rings as a *security risk* to me, but a simple check of https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint would have told you that it doesn't provide support beyond 18.04 so did you check?

Comment: FYI, you can find out if your current version of Ubuntu is supported by going to the launchpad page for the PPA as linked in the other comments. Then, you scroll down to where it says "Published in" and click on the drop down menu for "any series". This will display all available Ubuntu versions. As you can see the last Ubuntu version available was for Bionic (18.04).

Comment: Aside from your PPA issue, have you tried [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1344385/167115) to get your fingerprint reader working on 22.04? It looks like you might not even need the PPA.